# Not able to transfer value using Subscription in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using Subject & Subscription to transfer data between two components but it's not working for me.

// First Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { SettingsHelperService } from '../settings-screen/settings-helper.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-master-data-config',
  templateUrl: './master-data-config.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./master-data-config.component.css']
})
export class MasterDataConfigComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  zoneSelected: boolean = false;
  wingSelected: boolean = false;
  public subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private settingHelperService: SettingsHelperService) { }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe(); // onDestroy cancels the subscribe request
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.settingHelperService.getSelectedValue().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }

}
```

// Second Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SettingsHelperService } from './settings-helper.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings-screen',
  templateUrl: './settings-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings-screen.component.css']
})
export class SettingsScreenComponent implements OnInit {

  public UnitType = [
    {value: 'matric', viewValue: 'Matric'},
    {value: 'imperial', viewValue: 'Imperial'},
  ];

  zoneSelect: boolean = false;
  wingSelect: boolean = false;
  selectedUnitType: string;
  valueSelected = [];

  constructor(private settingHelperService: SettingsHelperService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  save(){
    let valueObj = {
      unitType: this.selectedUnitType,
      zoneSelect: this.zoneSelect,
      wingSelect: this.wingSelect
    }
    this.settingHelperService.setValues(valueObj);
  }

}
```

// Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SettingsHelperService {

  public unitType:string;
  public valueSubmitted = null;

  public data = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

  getSelectedValue(){
    return this.data.asObservable();
  }

  setValues(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.data.next(value);
  }

}
```

Please suggest where am I wrong..?

I'm not retrieving the updates values in component.

Comment: Where do you expect an output? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Try changing your Subject into a BehaviorSubject?

Comment: I think he needs a ReplaySubject because he might subscribe after a new value is nexted. Thats why I asked for more clarification what he wants to achieve. Thinking in an asynchronous way is not easy

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious problems with your code except that you didn't show the code where you provide the SettingHelperService. That could be an issue. If not correctly provided both components could have their own instance of the service and not sharing the same one. Try adding this code in the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

If that doesn't help then check this Stackblitz I made based on your code. After adding the above it works as it is: https://angular-ivy-g8keel.stackblitz.io